# Elastic Beanstalk set up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment with a new account.

I have myself set up with the full access on the following services:

- Access Analyzer
- Auto Scaling
- Certificate Manager
- Cloud Control API
- CloudFormation
- EC2
- Elastic Beanstalk
- ElastiCache
- IAM
- OpenSearch Service
- Pinpoint Email
- RDS
- Route 53
- S3
- SES
- SES v2

I am getting to following error

> Creating Auto Scaling launch configuration failed Reason: Resource
> handler returned message: "User:
> arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/IAMUserName is not
> authorized to perform: autoscaling:CreateLaunchConfiguration on
> resource:
> arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-2:542435368335:launchConfiguration:*:launchConfigurationName/awseb-e-xi8zxyphtb-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-qgdY1GNSwf60
> because no identity-based policy allows the
> autoscaling:CreateLaunchConfiguration action (Service: AutoScaling,
> Status Code: 403, Request ID: d4307ebf-1f5f-40ca-a867-3545c198b51f)"
> (RequestToken: 84675438-bcb3-6830-445d-97bfec2a06c7, HandlerErrorCode:
> GeneralServiceException)

I really don't understand the issue.  I have not experienced this before.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `autoscaling:CreateLaunchConfiguration` permissions to `IAMUserName`.